# How to check data distribution fit for censored data in survival analysis?

Tags: survival, nonparametric

I would like to check if the data I have follows a certain distribution and if I understand correctly, there are several statistical tests that can be used to determine this - Kolmogorov Smirnov Test, Anderson Darling test, etc but I have noticed that these tests are usually used for uncensored data.

If I have right censored data, are there any R packages that can be used to test the distribution assumptions?

Comment: Take a look at "A Cramer-von Mises Statistic for Randomly Censored Data" - I don't know if an R package implements it though

Comment: If you find something, please answer your original question!

Comment: Thanks. I will go with the suggestion from Todd below as it seems not trivial to do this inspection with censored data at the moment and doing a visual inspection might seem more useful for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Plot the empiric vs. modeled survival and do a visual inspection.
2. Calculate parametric or nonparametric models and choose the model with the lowest Akeike Information Criterion.

Comment: I just need to confirm something before accepting your solution. Once I have plotted the empirical vs modeled survival, does it make sense to then compute the predicted survival rate from the model against the observed survival rate and use the Kolmogorov Smirnov test to compare?

Comment: For most, maybe all, models where AIC is estimable, it can be used to determine the best model. You do not need KS test.

Comment: It depends on what question you're asking, however. The AIC method tells you which is the best parametric model out of the chosen ones, it does not say anything about how good of a fit any of them are. For example, if your application requires one to answer "does this data follow a log-normal?", then ranking AIC doesn't help with that.